# SQL Loop through result set to assign employees

Tags: sql-server, loops, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the result of a select query that returns (for example) 10,000 rows in a specific order by sequence (by priority)

I have 4 employees that I need to assign both equally in distribution (so everyone gets 2,500) AND by priority (so everyone gets an equalish amount of high priority work to complete)

I'm working with two simple sets...

My initial result set of 10,000 looks something like this:

```
Job Due Date    Assignment
a   11/1/2015   
b   11/1/2015   
c   11/2/2015   
d   11/3/2015   
e   11/4/2015   
f   11/4/2015   
g   11/4/2015   
h   11/4/2015   
i   11/5/2015
```

And my employees table is a simple:

```
Employees
Tom
Jerry
Susan
Rick
```

I need the end result to look something like:

```
Job Due Date    Assignment  
a   11/1/2015   Tom

b   11/1/2015   Jerry   
c   11/2/2015   Susan   

d   11/3/2015   Rick    
e   11/4/2015   Tom 

f   11/4/2015   Jerry   

g   11/4/2015   Susan   
h   11/4/2015   Rick    
i   11/5/2015   Tom
```

How can I iterate through my 10,000 records to assign my 4 employees at a time?

Comment: How?   With SQL.   What did you try, and what error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just need to divide the work by the date, you can do it using row_number to number the rows 0 .. 3 and create same kind of number to the employees like this, and then just update the values:

```
; with A as (
  select row_number() over (order by [Due Date]) % 4 as EmpNo, *
  from Assignment
), E as (
  select row_number() over (order by (select null)) % 4 as EmpNo, *
  from Employees
)

update A
set A.Employee = E.Employee
from 
E where E.EmpNo = A.EmpNo
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7d39/1)

Comment: Thank you JamesZ, this worked exactly as I needed it to!